# Linear mapping of a volume in 3 dimension

Tags: geometry

What would be the best method to map a three dimensional volumetric object onto a linear domain ? That is, I would like to map each point on the 3 dimensional domain onto a unique point on the linear domain uniquely. I should then be able to map back from the linear domain onto the three dimensional domain using some kind of mapping.

Comment: What do you mean by *linear domain*?

Comment: By linear domain, I meant the real axis

Comment: There is no invertible *linear* mapping from $\Bbb R^3$ to the real line. So either there is no way, or your title is misleading and you are not looking for a linear map. Are you sure you meant *linear mapping* in the title?

Comment: I was just searching around and came across the Hilbert space filling curve. Would it qualify as a solution?

Comment: The Hilbert space filling curve is not injective. But I see, you are not meaning *linear mapping* in the usual mathematical sense.

Comment: You are right. I'm not trained formally in math so pardon my laxity. How do you think the Hilbert curve works in my case?

Comment: The Hilbert curve will map different points of your object to the same points on the line. So it is not invertible. But because the real line and $\Bbb R^3$ are of the same cardinality, it is absolutely possible to map they into each other in an invertible fashion. See e.g. [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/947198/415941). But I am afraid that an *explicit construction* of such a mapping as you want it is not possible. But I may be wrong. Why do you need it? Maybe there is another solution.

Comment: Will a finite order Hilbert curve map onto the same point on real line as well? I'm looking to implement an algorithm so I would have to do with a finite discretion of the curve

Comment: The finite steps of the Hilbert curve do not assign the same point on the line to two space points, but they will also not hit all points on your 3D-object. Again, tell me why you want to achieve this and there might be another way.

Comment: I have a 3d object which has a non homogenous material distribution. I am looking to project this variation onto a linear domain. In this manner, I am trying to unravel the object into some kind of linear function

Comment: How is your object represented? Is it clustered in some finite grid (voxels)? What do you hope to get from this mapping? You want to compress it for data transfert? Almost surely all useful information is "lost" in the process of mapping and nothing can be seen from the "linear form" without transforming it back first. How do you want to respresent that mapping on the computer? Usually a computer can only deal with floating point numbers and not all real numbers which makes it a *very different* questions.

Comment: Yes. I am using a 3d mesh to represent the data. And you are absolutely right that I'm looking for data storage and compression. though I understand that floating point numbers have their limitations, I should still be able to at least theoretically associate a real number with a point though numerical limitations would crop up in my implementation

Comment: The problem with floating point numbers is that they are of a fixed size, e.g. $64$ bits. You cannot fit three of them into one without loosing precision. All I can think about is to shrink each of them to $64/2\approx 21$ bit and join them to a single $64$ bit floating point number. This is more a computer science task than a mathematical one.

Answer (score 1):

You can map discrete equidistant points in a volume using the following. 
Say there is 3D array of $N_1 \times N_2 \times N_3 $ points. This can be linearized to a 1D array where $(i, j, k)$ maps to $$(i, j, k)\rightarrow i+N_1\times j+N_1\times N_2 \times k$$

The right hand side is the index of the point in 1D array. Now you you mesh size is determined by $N\mathrm{'s}$. So however large volume you are trying to model you can do it with large enough $N\mathrm{'s}$.

Comment: This sort of resembles what you are asking for.